# How am I supposed to find where a PCI slot is in a laptop?

Tags: bios, pci

An old laptop I found (an an Acer Aspire 5100 series BL51) gives this error:

[image: picture of the message]

```
Phoenix TrustedCore(tm) NB
Copyright 1985-2005 Phoenix Technologies
All Rights Reserved

System BIOS Version: V2.00
    Bus:06, Device:02, Function:00
ERROR
Resource Conflict - PCI in slot 03
    Bus:06, Device:04, Function:00
ERROR
Resource Conflict - PCI in slot 03
    Bus:06, Device:04, Function:01
ERROR
Resource Conflict - PCI in slot 03
    Bus:06, Device:04, Function:02
ERROR
Resource Conflict - PCI in slot 03
    Bus:06, Device:04, Function:03
```

Based off of that error, I'm assuming there is a problem with PCI in slot 03, which I'm also assuming the item inserted into the PCI slot 03, but I cannot find which slot is which because they're not labelled or anything. I've tried looking on the Acer website but most things 404 and a PDF of the manual I found has nothing useful at all.

Without the manual, how can I find the problematic PCI slot and fix the issue?

Comment: If this is a laptop, then the things in the "PCI Slots" will actually be hardwired in, as there's no actual PCI expansion slots, just the lanes they used when hardwiring in a "PCI" sub-device on the motherboard (in most cases).

Comment: The RAM and the WLAN card aren't hard wired in, so I'm hoping whatever is in slot 03 isn't hard wired in, what could possible causer a "Resource conflict" ?

Comment: RAM doesn't use a PCI interface, and if you suspect it's the WiFi card (which may be PCI), why not pull it out and see if the error goes away?  Resource Conflicts are cause by multiple devices trying to use the same resource (like an IRQ, or memory address) at the same time.

Comment: I have not seen these times of errors for over a decade and a half how old is this laptop?  What happens when you hit F1 to continue

Comment: pressing F1 will just take me to a flashing underscore

Comment: Remove the wireless card and see if the problem still appears.

Comment: I removed it and the same thing happened, 2 audible beeps and then that error

Comment: Your laptop is around 7 years old, and a dead motherboard at this age is no great shock. You can still pull the hard drive and get the data off of it, but aside from that I think you're going to have to write this one off.

Answer (score 1):

The PCI device could be the Bluetooth, network card or any other optional device (other than the keyboard, touchpad, HD and CD/DVD).
According to the manual, this model has an optional TV card and webcam. 
If you can get to the BIOS and experiment by disabling everything except the HD, that might help isolate things.
Otherwise, the standard approach is to remove everything except the HD, keyboard and memory and try isolating things that way.

Comment: How do I disable it in the bios?